# How to add wildcards in lookahead?

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'd like to identify certain values in the following string, specially the values inside CVC and Number:

`CreditCard Number="123" CVC="213" Date="2015-12"`

`(?<=CVC=\").*(?=")` matches `213" Date="2015-12`. How can I modify the regex to look for the first doublequote match after something was found, and not to look for the last doublequote as it does now?

Further: how can I define wildcards in lookaheads? Ideally I'd like to have an expression:
`(?<=CreditCard.*CVC=\").*(?=")` which means that a CVC statement must be preceded with "CreditCard" String, but between them there could by any values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply make the `.*` not greedy `.*?`

```
(?<=CVC=\").*?(?=")
```

[RegExr](http://regexr.com?37cij)

In answer to your 2nd question, java regex (and most other engines) don't allow variable length lookbehinds. Usually though, you can solve a problem that would require a variable length lookbehind by using capture groups:

```
(?<=CreditCard.*CVC=\").*?(?=")
```

becomes:

```
CreditCard.*?CVC=\"(.*?)"
```

And then you can take the relevant information from capture group 1. 
[RegExr](http://regexr.com?37cid) (`.*` added on RegExr so that output replaces the entire input, its not required for your case though.)

Comment: Question is, do you really need the lookahead/behind in this case, or could you just match `CreditCard.*CVC=\"(.*?)"` and grab the first capture group?

Comment: Well I'd like to grab what's inside of the double quotes. You regex would match anything including the string creditCard and cvc, wouldn't it?

Comment: @OGHaza I guess GMTA. +1 for your answer.

Comment: @membersound I've probably simplified the last regex since you commented, but I assure you it didn't

Comment: How did you test this? I usually use http://gskinner.com/RegExr/, and with this the result is not as I'd intend...

Comment: I just tested it since you commented and both work correctly. Feel free to give me a permalink to your broken case. I'll add working example links to the answer.

Comment: http://regexr.com?37cia this would also match the CreditCard and number string...

Comment: You are only going to use the contents of capture group 1 though. On RegExr you can set it to replace mode and put the replace text as `[$1-$1-$1]`, then you'll see a `[213-213-213]` in the output since `213` is captured in `$1`

Comment: Ok I see. Could you also give me a hint to how the numbers in CVC could only be replaced, and the rest of the content is preserved. Because that is why I intended to find the CVC values out with regex...

Comment: I mean, I could do it like this: http://regexr.com?37cim but this again would not take the CreditCard string preceeded into account...

Comment: So in the example `213` is the only thing you want to replace?

Comment: I could also imagine to replace all sensitive details, like also `Number="123"`, but if I have one example, I could adapt the others...

Answer (score 0):

You could skip using lookbehinds, and instead use clustering to pull out just the portions of the string you want:

```
CreditCard Number="(/d*)".*\sCVC="(/d*)"
```

And then the "match groups" numbered 1 and 2 will correspond to your credit card number and CVC, respectively.  (You can use `Matcher.group(int)` to retrieve the values of the various groups)  Notice that by using `\d` to specifically match digits, you don't have to make the `*` non-greedy.  In this case it works because you only want to match on digits.  In the general case (let's say a credit card number could consist of any non-quote character), you can use a custom character class to match anything but your delimiter (quote in this case):

```
CreditCard Number="([^"]*)".*\sCVC="([^"]*)"
```